# Best way to change screen in React when URL not updated

Tags: reactjs, render

I have an app I'm building in React where the url never updates despite each screen taking up the entire page.

What is the best way to render each screen when it's the screen to be viewed?

```
export const App = () => {
  const [activeScreen, setActiveScreen] = useState("PAGE_1");
  const goToScreen2 = () => setActiveScreen("PAGE_2");
  const goToScreen3 = () => setActiveScreen("PAGE_3");

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {activeScreen === "PAGE_1" &&
        <Page1 nextScreen={goToScreen2} />
      }

      {activeScreen === "PAGE_2" && 
        <Page2 nextScreen={goToScreen3} />
      }

      {activeScreen === "PAGE_3" &&
        <Page3 />
      }
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are the pages going to be shown in a linear order ?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router ?

Comment: @Treycos yes they will be shown in a linear order, in the order they are in above.

Comment: @thedude I've used it with plenty of other apps, but wasn't sure if that was the right solution to use when the url isn't being updated at all.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that was the desired behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```js
function Page1() {
  return 'Page 1'
}

function Page2() {
  return 'Page 2'
}

function Page3() {
  return 'Page 3'
}

function Pager({
  next,
  prev,
  children
}) {
  return ( 
  <div>
    <button onClick={prev}>Prev</button>
    {children} 
    <button onClick={next}>Next</button> 
  </div>
  )
}



const pages = [Page1, Page2, Page3]

const App = () => {
  const [activeScreen, setActiveScreen] = React.useState(0);
  const goNext = () => setActiveScreen((activeScreen + 1) % pages.length);
  const goBack = () => setActiveScreen((activeScreen - 1 + pages.length) % pages.length);

  const ActivePage = pages[activeScreen]

  return ( 
    <Pager next={goNext} prev={goBack}>
      <ActivePage />
    </Pager>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```